# residual analysis based on the results of Chi-squared test of independence in R

Tags: r, chi-squared

How can I do a residual analysis based on the results of Chi-squared test of independence in R like the picture?

```
## From Agresti(2007) p.39
M <- as.table(rbind(c(762, 327, 468), c(484, 239, 477)))
dimnames(M) <- list(gender = c("F", "M"),
                    party = c("Democrat","Independent", "Republican"))
(Xsq <- chisq.test(M))  # Prints test summary\
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access the standardised residuals under `chsq$stdres` where `chsq` is the `chisq.test` return object.

To use the example from `?chisq.test`

```
M <- as.table(rbind(c(762, 327, 468), c(484, 239, 477)))
dimnames(M) <- list(
    gender = c("F", "M"),
    party = c("Democrat","Independent", "Republican"))

chsq <- chisq.test(M)

chsq$stdres
#      party
#gender   Democrat Independent Republican
#     F  4.5020535   0.6994517 -5.3159455
#     M -4.5020535  -0.6994517  5.3159455
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer:

```
df <- as.data.frame(M)
df

library(gmodels)

x <- CrossTable(df$gender, 
           df$party, 

           chisq=T, 
           expected=T, 
           asresid=T, 
           format="SPSS", 
           prop.t=F, 
           prop.chisq=F, 
           prop.r=F, 
           prop.c=F, 
           digits=2)
```

[image]